# If $-1<\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right)<1$ then there exists the limit $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\sum _{k=0}^n\:\:x_k\right)$

Tags: limits

Let be $x_n$ a sequence.
Prove that if $$-1<\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right)<1$$ then there exists the limit of the sequence
$$y_n=\sum _{k=1}^nx_k\:$$ and it is finite.

I am not one hundred percent that this is completely true. In any event, I managed to show that if
$$0<\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right)<1$$
then the sequence
$$y_n=\sum _{k=1}^nx_k\:$$
is convergent owing to the fact that it is not only bounded but it is also increasingly from a certain rank $n_0.$

Moreover, I proved that if
$$-1<\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right)<0$$
then the sequence
$$y_n=\sum _{k=1}^nx_k\:$$
is convergent as well since it is bounded and decreasingly from a certain rank $n_1$.
However I still have to prove this for the case
$$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right)=0$$
Can somebody help me out?

Comment: It is given that $\lim \frac {x_{n+1}} {x_n}$ exist. So $\lim \frac {|x_{n+1}|} {|x_n|}$ exists too and ratio test applies.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to imply, unfortunately. Try to be more precise. Also what is $a_n$

Answer (score 2):

As Kavi Rama Murthy said in the comments, if the limit of $\frac {x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ exists then its absolute value also exists.
You can then apply the ratio test (Dalambert criterion) which requires all elements $a_n \gt 0$ and that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n} = r$.
When $r \lt 1$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges.

Comment: Can you come up with the full proof please?

Comment: @shangq_tou Or you could complete the proof yourself using the sketch I just provided. You just have to fill in some rather obvious and trivial blanks ;-)

Comment: Then your answer should have been a comment to the post. You have to come up with the proof to Dalambert criterion

Comment: I provided a sketch of a proof, remember that we're not here to do your homeworks for you :)
Do you have a particular question or doubt about the sketch I provided?

Comment: Unfortunately, your post is irrelevant as long as I'm trying to prove my statement only for a certain case only by using elementary theorems and propositions. Therefore it must be removed

Comment: Oh my... you're missing the trees in the forest. As I stated: whenever $r \lt 1$ then the series converges. Notice that $0 \lt 1$.

Comment: I haven't heard of Dalambert criterion therefore a proof might be useful. Of course, I know $0<1$ :))